# Regex to find word but only finding first line item

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex to find a certain list of tags. (3 Results)

```
<li><font color=\""Red\"" size=\""5\""><b>(.*?)</b>
```

I then wanted to take it further and only bring back the ones with the word Critical.

```
<li><font color=\""Red\"" size=\""5\""><b>(.*Critical.*?)</b>
```

However, this only brings back the first one. I have 3 `<li>` tags and 2 of them contain critical.  Is there a way to modify this to include all of the ones that contain the word Critical?

This is what the example of what I would be trying to find 1 and 3 but right now only line 1 is returning.

```
<li><font color="Red" size="5"><b>Critical - This would be line 1</b></font></li>
<li><font color="Red" size="5"><b>This would be line 2</b></font></li>
<li><font color="Red" size="5"><b>Critical - This would be line 3</b></font></li>
```

****Solution** that ended up working for my needs.

```
<li><font color=\"Red\" size=\"5\"><b>([^<]*Critical.*?)</b>
```

Comment: Are you certain that your regex is doing global match and also multi-line?  Typically by default if you hit a newline, the regex will stop.

Comment: Doesn't C# have any libraries for parsing HTML without resorting to fragile pure-Regex solutions?

Comment: Made an edit to hopefully help.  Well that's odd, I have it sent to IgnoreCase and Singleline and the first one, (.*?) returns all 3.  It's once I add Critical it goes weird.

Comment: @Alvin Wong: In a Perl-compatible regular expression, `.*?` is a non-greedy match, whereas `.*` is greedy.  It basically says to match as **few** characters possible to find the next anchor, rather than the **most** characters possible (which would be default).

Comment: @DavidO well I just forgot that, but in this case I would write `[^<]*`, although likely to make no difference

Comment: @Alvin Wong: Certainly being more explicit than the ill-chosen "dot-star" is a good thing, but even that is fragile.  I still think there must be a C# library that can parse HTML.

Comment: seems that the first `.*` in the second RegEx will be too greedy, is it?

Comment: ...and in fact, there **is** a C# HTML parser:  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/  This will be immensely more robust than a fragile pure-Regex solution.

Comment: For the really small instance that this is going to be used, it doesn't necessitate the whole agility pack, its a small page.  It looks like this works. <li><font color=\"Red\" size=\"5\"><b>([^<]*Critical.*?)</b>

Comment: Successful small projects tend to bloom and eventually one ends up pouring through many lines of code stamping out all those shortcuts that stifle maintainability and scalability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Alvin Wong above led to this working for what I needed.  Finds all the instances with Critical in between the tag.

```
<li><font color=\"Red\" size=\"5\"><b>([^<]*Critical.*?)</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try {
    Regex RegexObj = new Regex("<li><font color=\"Red\" size=\"5\"><b>(.*Critical.*?)</b>");
    Match MatchResults = RegexObj.Match(YourString);
    while (MatchResults.Success) {

        MatchResults = MatchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```